# How to search with multidimensional array search in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm getting the arrays I want get the price accroding to the ID and the quantity. this is my array can you please help me how to do this in using array search function. Please help me slove this issue.

**This is my array view**

Here i'm paasing the dm_id , decoration_code, q1 accroding to this value i want to get the one of the p value (p mean price)

```
$dm_id = LL0007;
$decoration_code = LL0007C9;
$quantity =  50;

original result = p1 = 0.25

How can get this result when I use the arrary search?

array:3 [▼
  0 => array:24 [▼
    "dm_id" => "LL0007"
    "decoration_code" => "LL0007B9"
    "decoration_name" => "Undecorated"
    "main_decoration" => "LL0007_LLNZ"
    "setup_change" => "0"
    "show_to_clients" => "1"
    "q1" => "50"
    "p1" => "0"
    "q2" => "100"
    "p2" => "0"
    "q3" => "250"
    "p3" => "0"
    "q4" => "500"
    "p4" => "0"
    "q5" => "0"
    "p5" => "0"
    "q6" => "0"
    "p6" => "0"
  ]
  1 => array:24 [▼
    "dm_id" => "LL0007"
    "decoration_code" => "LL0007C9"
    "decoration_name" => "1 Colour 1 Position Print"
    "main_decoration" => "LL0007_LLNZ"
    "setup_change" => "35"
    "show_to_clients" => "1"
    "q1" => "50"
    "p1" => "0.25"
    "q2" => "100"
    "p2" => "0.25"
    "q3" => "250"
    "p3" => "0.25"
    "q4" => "500"
    "p4" => "0.25"
    "q5" => "0"
    "p5" => "0"
    "q6" => "0"
    "p6" => "0"
  ]
  2 => array:24 [▼
    "dm_id" => "LL0007"
    "decoration_code" => "LL0007D9"
    "decoration_name" => "1 Position Digital Print"
    "main_decoration" => "LL0007_LLNZ"
    "setup_change" => "35"
    "show_to_clients" => "1"
    "q1" => "50"
    "p1" => "0.4"
    "q2" => "100"
    "p2" => "0.4"
    "q3" => "250"
    "p3" => "0.4"
    "q4" => "500"
    "p4" => "0.4"
    "q5" => "0"
    "p5" => "0"
    "q6" => "0"
    "p6" => "0"
  ]
]
```

Comment: In general: You either loop over the array yourself, and check if the current item fulfills all your criteria - or you use `array_filter`, and let your callback fuction do the checking. But - you don't _know_ yet, that you want the `p1` value - if the quantity you are looking for was 100 instead of 50, then you would need the `p2` value instead. So you will have to loop over the `qX` properties as well, to find your correct `X` first of all.

Comment: With two "foreach" loops I succeeded in developing the code (and this regardless of the number of existing quantity or price). Did you try a code that we can see...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know maybe I shouldn't answer (because very little information was given and no code was shown) but here is the code I found. It works but I don't know if there is better to do.

```
// Initialization
$dm_id = "LL0007";
$decoration_code = "LL0007C9";
$quantity = 50;
$price = 0;

// For Each Product
foreach($productList as $productKey => $productInfo)
{
    // If Product Identified
    if( ($productInfo["dm_id"]==$dm_id) && ($productInfo["decoration_code"]==$decoration_code) )
    {
        // For Each Info
        foreach($productInfo as $keyInfo => $valueInfo)
        {
            // If Good Info "Quantity"
            if( (substr($keyInfo,0,1)=="q") && (bcmul($valueInfo,1,0)>0) )
            {
                // If Quantity is Correcte
                if(bcmul($valueInfo,1,0)<=bcmul($quantity,1,0)) $price = $productInfo["p".substr($keyInfo,1,1).""];
            }
            // End - If Good Info "Quantity"
        }
        // End - For Each Info
    }
    // End - If Product Identified      
}
// End - For Each Product

// Display Result
echo "<b>".$price."</b>";
```

Product List is the array shown in the code in question.

Comment: Thank you so much. This code is 100% working.